# How do I split string values on bases of Bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to split my column ACCEPTED_LOCATION by 25 bytes, 13 bytes, 2 bytes.

The characters aren't constant so i cant use split or sub string. Either i can split it where there are 2 spaces or by number of bytes.

The first 25 bytes represent the location, 13 bytes represent the city, 2 bytes represent the country code

[image: Click to view data]

Comment: You say you can split when there are 2 spaces. Why not just do ```.split(2 * " ")``` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youll eed to make a temp df with wanted data,
this will work good for decent amounts of data

creating content:

```
arr1 = [x[0:25] for x in df.ACCEPTED_LOCATION.values]
arr2 = [x[25:48] for x in df.ACCEPTED_LOCATION.values]
arr3 = [x[48:] for x in df.ACCEPTED_LOCATION.values]
```

inserting into df:

```
df[['col1','col2', 'col3']] = pd.DataFrame({1: arr1,2: arr2, 3: arr3}, index=df.index)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: make sure arr1,2,3 are all in the same length, and not including any nulls, if you string length is shorter then what im trying to cut out from it, this will result in an error, which line throws you the error?

Comment: No this is constantly dividing it by the character count. I want to separate it using number of bytes. Is there a way to separate if more than 2 spaces occur

Comment: How do i separate it using bytes

Comment: a char is always a singled byte, so there isnt suppose to be the same.. but change the seperation code, the rest should work

Comment: Then you are more than welcome to mark it as the correct answer :)